# Use custom post field to Woocmmerce title loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I'm using Wordpress custom post field for my products in Woocommerce.

I've created a custom field called 'phone_model' and it will contain strings like 'iPhone 6 Plus' etc.

In my child theme functions.php I've added this function:

```
function wc_phone_model(){
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
    $phone_model = $custom_fields['phone_model'];
    if (is_array($phone_model)) {
        foreach ( $phone_model as $key => $value ) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

It's working as expected. It will show the given value in the custom post field.

In my Woocommerce title loop title.php, I've added this line:

```
<div class="phone_model_wrap"><span class="phone_model"><?php wc_phone_model() ?></span></div>
```

How do I make this show only if there is something to show from the custom post field?

Thanks in advance guys!

Cheers Kenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there is a stigma against echoing html, but in this case, I can't think of a better way. I'd recommend something like this:

```
function wc_phone_model(){
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
    $phone_model = $custom_fields['phone_model'];
    if (is_array($phone_model)) {
        echo '<div class="phone_model_wrap"><span class="phone_model">';
        foreach ( $phone_model as $key => $value ) {
            echo $value;
        }
        echo '</span></div>';
    }
}
```

Then in your title.php, its just a matter of calling the function.

```
<?php wc_phone_model() ?>
```

If someone has a clean solution without echoing html though, I'd be interested in seeing it!

Comment: This is awesome! 
And then a pretty solution to the loop, and everything else to the function. 
I will keep watching if a more clean solution comes up!
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

@kunruh
I have faced another problem with your solution.
I have made a new function to be used elsewhere with another class etc.

```
function wc_phone_model_single_product(){
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
    $phone_model = $custom_fields['phone_model'];
    if (is_array($phone_model)) {
        echo '<div class="phone_model_wrap"><span class="phone_model_single_product">Til ';
        foreach ( $phone_model as $key => $value ) {
            echo $value;
        }
        echo '</span></div>';
    }
}
```

The "Til" will be echoed even if there is nothing in $phone_model.
How do I avoid this?

Cheers Kenn

Comment: It has been solved. I would gladly share if anyone would like.